# Issue with adding questions in Android game

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm a beginner in Android Studio and Java and I'm almost complete with my first Android application, however, I'm trying to add more than 5 questions but when I add question 6 it is not showing up. Here's the code from my DbHelper.java class:

```
package com.example.triviality;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "triviaQuiz";
    // tasks table name
    private static final String TABLE_QUEST = "quest";
    // tasks Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_QUES = "question";
    private static final String KEY_ANSWER = "answer"; //correct option
    private static final String KEY_OPTA= "opta"; //option a
    private static final String KEY_OPTB= "optb"; //option b
    private static final String KEY_OPTC= "optc"; //option c
    private SQLiteDatabase dbase;
    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        dbase=db;
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST + " ( "
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_QUES
                + " TEXT, " + KEY_ANSWER+ " TEXT, "+KEY_OPTA +" TEXT, "
                +KEY_OPTB +" TEXT, "+KEY_OPTC+" TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(sql);
        addQuestions();
        db.close();
    }
    private void addQuestions()
    {
        Question q1=new Question("Which company is the largest manufacturer" +
                " of network equipment?","HP", "IBM", "CISCO", "CISCO");
        this.addQuestion(q1);
        Question q2=new Question("Which of the following is NOT " +
                "an operating system?", "SuSe", "BIOS", "DOS", "BIOS");
        this.addQuestion(q2);
        Question q3=new Question("Which of the following is the fastest" +
                " writable memory?","RAM", "FLASH","Register","Register");
        this.addQuestion(q3);
        Question q4=new Question("Which of the following device" +
                " regulates internet traffic?", "Router", "Bridge", "Hub","Router");
        this.addQuestion(q4);
        Question q5=new Question("Which of the following is NOT an" +
                " interpreted language?","Ruby","Python","BASIC","BASIC");
        this.addQuestion(q5);
        Question q6 = new Question("2+2 is equal to" +
                " which of the following?","0","22","4","4");
        this.addQuestion(q6);
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldV, int newV) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST);
        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }
    // Adding new question
    public void addQuestion(Question quest) {
        //SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_QUES, quest.getQUESTION());
        values.put(KEY_ANSWER, quest.getANSWER());
        values.put(KEY_OPTA, quest.getOPTA());
        values.put(KEY_OPTB, quest.getOPTB());
        values.put(KEY_OPTC, quest.getOPTC());
        // Inserting Row
        dbase.insert(TABLE_QUEST, null, values);
    }
    public List<Question> getAllQuestions() {
        List<Question> quesList = new ArrayList<Question>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST;
        dbase=this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = dbase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Question quest = new Question();
                quest.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
                quest.setQUESTION(cursor.getString(1));
                quest.setANSWER(cursor.getString(2));
                quest.setOPTA(cursor.getString(3));
                quest.setOPTB(cursor.getString(4));
                quest.setOPTC(cursor.getString(5));
                quesList.add(quest);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        // return quest list
        return quesList;
    }
    public int rowcount()
    {
        int row=0;
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        row=cursor.getCount();
        return row;
    }
}
```

I change the code from this one:

```
private void addQuestions()
    {
        Question q1=new Question("Which company is the largest manufacturer" +
                " of network equipment?","HP", "IBM", "CISCO", "CISCO");
        this.addQuestion(q1);
        Question q2=new Question("Which of the following is NOT " +
                "an operating system?", "SuSe", "BIOS", "DOS", "BIOS");
        this.addQuestion(q2);
        Question q3=new Question("Which of the following is the fastest" +
                " writable memory?","RAM", "FLASH","Register","Register");
        this.addQuestion(q3);
        Question q4=new Question("Which of the following device" +
                " regulates internet traffic?", "Router", "Bridge", "Hub","Router");
        this.addQuestion(q4);
        Question q5=new Question("Which of the following is NOT an" +
                " interpreted language?","Ruby","Python","BASIC","BASIC");
        this.addQuestion(q5);
    }
```

to this one, which I try to add question 6 but it does not show up:

```
private void addQuestions()
    {
        Question q1=new Question("Which company is the largest manufacturer" +
                " of network equipment?","HP", "IBM", "CISCO", "CISCO");
        this.addQuestion(q1);
        Question q2=new Question("Which of the following is NOT " +
                "an operating system?", "SuSe", "BIOS", "DOS", "BIOS");
        this.addQuestion(q2);
        Question q3=new Question("Which of the following is the fastest" +
                " writable memory?","RAM", "FLASH","Register","Register");
        this.addQuestion(q3);
        Question q4=new Question("Which of the following device" +
                " regulates internet traffic?", "Router", "Bridge", "Hub","Router");
        this.addQuestion(q4);
        Question q5=new Question("Which of the following is NOT an" +
                " interpreted language?","Ruby","Python","BASIC","BASIC");
        this.addQuestion(q5);
        Question q6 = new Question("2+2 is equal to" +
                " which of the following?","0","22","4","4");
        this.addQuestion(q6);
    }
```

Could someone please help me? The tutorial that I'm using is from this [website](https://www.developerfeed.com/simple-quiz-game-andriod/), and the code that I'm using is available from this [link](http://www.developerfeed.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Triviality.zip).

Comment: By `does not show up` do you mean you don't see the question in the database?

Comment: You need to post more of the code and explain better. Such as what `addQuestion()` actually does and how you're trying to display these.

Comment: codeMagic No, I mean that it does not show up when I run the app, and I posted more code

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is with this bit of code

> public void onClick(View v) {...if(qid<5){
>   currentQ=quesList.get(qid);
>   setQuestionView();
>   }else{....

If the question id is less than 5 then show the next question, else show your score. Since you now have 6 questions you should change the `if qid < 5` to `if qid < 6`.

Comment: This is correct for a simple static fix, but for something more dynamic he could do something like `if(qid < quesList.size())...` (which is a complete assumption as I didn't dig through the code like you did :P)

Comment: @zgc7009 Agreed, just didn't want to add too much for a beginner. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the help but now, the app is throwing me a fatal exception IndexOutOfBounds Exception, Invalid Index 5 size is five. What do I do now?

Comment: I think you will need to debug the app, I can't be the human debugger right now. :P)